# display variable html image

Tags: html, image, src

In Angular 2 code, I have defined the  image as:

```
public rObj:any = {};
this.rObj.imgsrc ="http:/../.png";
```

Want to render this from my HTML:

```
<img src = {{rObj.imgsrc}}>
```

There is no display.Any help appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Not developing in Angular2... but maybe you need to remove the space between `src`, `=` and the variable as well.

Comment: @lumio No, that would not be an issue.

Comment: @Rob ok :) I thought so.

Comment: @gacha, what is your web dev console output?

Answer (score 0):

Use one way binding on the src attribute.  Any html attribute can be bound to.

... so for you this is what you are looking for.

```
<img [src]="rObj.imgsrc" />
```

Another example..

```
<a [href]="myHref"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong data binding:

- string binding: `<elt attr="Hello World"/>`
- input (component → template): `<elt [attr]="x"/>`
- event listener (template → component): `<button (click)="someFunction"/>`
- two-way data binding: `<elt [(attr)]="x"/>` (not used a lot, use [forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) instead)

So you actually need here to write `<img [src]="rObj.imgsrc"/>`

Comment: I tried this:<img [src]="rObj.imgsrc"/>,but getting broken link.In angular 2,it is public rObj:any={};

Comment: Are you sure your image exists and can be accessed by the front-end?